# How to implement protected parent class field from child class in Codeigniter constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a base controller which has base methods

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Championship extends CI_Controller {

  protected $championship_id;

  public function __construct($_championship_id)
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $championship_id = $_championship_id;
  } 

  public function results($page)
  {
     //Some code here
  }


}
```

And when I try to implement My_Championship class in another controller the output is empty even when I pass parameter '1' in the constructor

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once("application/core/MY_Championship.php");

class Eurobasket2017 extends MY_Championship {

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct(1);
      file_put_contents("test.txt", $this->championship_id);    
  }
}
```

The main problem is that depending on which parameter I give the constructor it changes records from the database: for example if I give parameter 1 it loads eurobasket games and if I give parameter 2 it loads nba games and so on..

Comment: Did sietse85's answer help you? If so, please accept his answer. If not, please comment on his answer.

Comment: well yeah getting used to not getting credit haha ;)

Answer (score 3):

Class MY_Championship constructor does not update its own instances championship_id property

change

```
$championship_id = $_championship_id;
```

into

```
$this->championship_id = $_championship_id;
```

If you don't do this the 
    $championship_id var will be lost as soon as the parent constructor is finished.